# Show buttons to user to select in botframework

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to display buttons for selecting city for user like i have following cities: 
cleveland, columbus, delaware, mayfield

How can show these as buttons in botframework? I can do this with forms like:

```
[Prompt("Please select what {&} you are in? {||}")]
public City? City;
public static IForm<SandwichOrder> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<SandwichOrder>()
            .Message("Welcome to the simple City bot!")
            .Build();
}
```

But the app i am creating is not a form and there are no more synchronized questions. So what is other simpler way of showing cities for user to select?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cards.

Jast add some to your activity object and wait for user response.

They have some special **Receipt Card** (a card that lets the user deliver an invoice or receipt).

> Bot Builder for .NET / Connector Service / Attachments, Cards and Actions

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html

Sample of how to add pair of buttons:

```
Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"");
    reply.Recipient = activity.From;
    reply.Type = "message";
    reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();

    List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
    CardAction cityBtn1 = new CardAction()
    {
        Value = "cleveland",
        Type = "postBack",
        Title = "Cleveland"
    };
    cardButtons.Add(cityBtn1);

    CardAction cityBtn2 = new CardAction()
    {
        Value = "columbus",
        Type = "postBack",
        Title = "Columbus"
    };
    cardButtons.Add(cityBtn2);

    HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
    {
        Title = "Please select what city you are in?",
        Buttons = cardButtons
    };
    Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
    reply.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on which channel you use, if your property is enum, web chat will show them as a list to choose and slack will show buttons